# iOS App rejected with reason of Your app includes non-iOS platform references and the ability to purchase these devices in the binary

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have developed an online shopping app for leading mobile retailer in India. This app allows customers to purchase all kind of mobiles, tablets and gadgets. But App Store rejected app a couple of times with the following reason.

**Guideline 2.3.10 - Performance - Accurate Metadata**

> We noticed that your app or its metadata includes irrelevant third-party platform information. Specifically, your app includes non-iOS platform references and the ability to purchase these devices in the binary. Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its metadata is not permitted on the App Store unless there is specific interactive functionality.

Next Steps

> To resolve this issue, please remove all instances of this information from your app and its metadata, including the app description, promotional text, What's New info, previews, and screenshots.

The information which I provided in App Store Connect

Name : App Name

Subtitle: Mobiles & Accessories

Promotional Text: You can now just sit back and relax once you have placed an order with us.

Description: App Name™ is the leading mobile retailer in India, for the latest branded mobile phones, tablets and a wide range of gadgets. Being established in 1989, it is the rapidly growing mobile showroom in India with more than 75 showrooms and 12 thousand delighted customers.

Keywords: Provided Only App Name as keyword

As I followed with the next steps which review team has suggested, I didn’t find any third platform information in my Description, promotional text and etc. So I asked them to specify more information about rejection, they replied with the below message.

> During our review we found that the main feature set of this app revolved around selling a large number of non-iOS devices and hardware which is not appropriate for the App Store.

What I understood from the above message is my app can’t offer to purchase non-iOS devices with this app. But main functionality is to offer purchase all kind of devices(both iOS and non-iOS) with this app.

So help me out how to get approved this app.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apple says they won't approve your app because its main feature is x. You say the app's main functionality is x, and ask how get the app approved. Under these conditions — that app, generating that response from Apple — I don't think you can get it accepted. You can rewrite the app to reduce or remove its listing of non-iOS devices and hardware, or you can move on to another project.

Comment: @David I'm sure Amazon also selling large number of non-iOS devices through their app. And our competitor also had iOS app in store with the same functionality of my app.

Comment: Is your competitor's app still listed in the App Store? If so, have you pointed this out to Apple? As to Google: Apple has, at different times and regarding different subjects, been both aggressive and conciliatory towards Google. Because of Google's size, I think it's unreasonable to assume that you can convince Apple to treat you in the same manner.

Comment: is this solved yet? i would suggest to make an exception for ios app... favour Apple device as default put it on main page. promotion during the review. and android device only visible on search function or after a while of browsing preference